# Sorting to find a target pair

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Hi guys I found this interesting application of sorting in one book:

> Finding a target pair - How can we test whether there are two integers x, y members of set S such that x+y=z for some target z? Instead of testing all possible pairs, sort the numbers in increasing order and sweep. As S[i] increases with i, its possible partner j such that S[j]=z-S[i] decreases. Thus decreasing j appropriately as i increases gives a nice solution.

I ve spent a lot of time trying to figure out how this application of sorting works but couldn't do it. Can you pls help?

Comment: The best way of 'trying to figure out' is to show the code you have and tell us where you have trouble with. Currently your question basically asks 'write the code'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine this set:

```
[1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 13, 14, 17]
```

You have to find a pair `x, y` of numbers in this set such that `x+y = 17`.

If your set is unsorted, you can check every possible pair, which is long (has a O(n2) complexity).

If your set is sorted, you can just start with the first and last numbers as `x` and `y`, and move through the set by increasing `x` and decreasing `y`:

```
1 + 17 --> Too big --> Decrease y
1 + 14 --> Too small --> Increase x
2 + 14 --> Too small --> Increase x
4 + 14 --> Too big --> Decrease y
4 + 13 = 17. STOP, you found a pair!
```

This has a O(nlogn) complexity for sorting, and a O(n) complexity for finding the pair.